# databricks unable to resolve custom log appender

Tags: log4j, azure-databricks

I'm trying to send over logs from databricks cluster to LogDNA, for which I do have a custom appender in place which works fine with the unit test in the sense I can see the logs coming over. But now when I'm trying to integrate it with Databricks as guided by [this](https://kb.databricks.com/clusters/overwrite-log4j-logs.html), databricks can't resolve the classPath. The init script that I'm loading into the cluster looks like following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Executing on Driver: $DB_IS_DRIVER"
if [[ $DB_IS_DRIVER = "TRUE" ]]; then
LOG4J_PATH="/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/dbconf/log4j/driver/log4j.properties"
else
LOG4J_PATH="/home/ubuntu/databricks/spark/dbconf/log4j/executor/log4j.properties"
fi
echo "log4j path : $LOG4J_PATH"
echo "log4j.rootLogger=INFO, LogDNAAppender, console" >> ${LOG4J_PATH}
echo "log4j.appender.LogDNAAppender=tools.logdna.util.LogDNAAppender" >> ${LOG4J_PATH}
echo "log4j.appender.LogDNAAppender.name=LogDNAAppender" >> ${LOG4J_PATH}
// and then properties associated with the appender
```

This script(to the init script) and dependency are successfully uploaded to the cluster, but then in runtime, it errors out as:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [tools.logdna.util.LogDNAAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tools.logdna.util.LogDNAAppender
```

Is there anything I'm missing or need to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was, I was uploading the dependencies to libraries in the databricks cluster which was sufficient for all of my cases until this point, but apparently not for the init scripts and it's /databricks/jars in the host(where I didn't have those jars) that's looked for in the runtime causing the ClassNotFoundException. The workaround was to put those jars in the correct folder i.e /databricks/jars.

Answer (score 0):

Add `logback-logdna` to the Databricks's classpath which would help Classloader to locate and load the `LogDNAAppender` class.

[Download logback-logdna](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.zileo/logback-logdna/1.0.1)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, but I have my own version of the custom log4j appender which the cluster is unable to find in the classpath, though I can verify via notebook I can access the Appender